# R shiny: selectizeGroupUI does not line up correctly

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinywidgets

Im new to R shiny and have ran into a weird issue. Im using a selectizeGroupUI function to have some filter inputs in the UI. for some reason one of my filter options always lines up oddly. Ive attached the code from my UI below along with a screenshot of the actual output. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    titlePanel(h1("Powered")),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "vars",
          label = h3("Filters:"),
          choices = c("Program", "Site", "Buyer", "Part_Number"),
          selected = c("Program", "Site", "Buyer", "Part_Number")
        ),
        panel(
        column(
          width = 8, 
          selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "my-filters",
          params = list(
            Program = list(inputId = "Program", label = h5("Program:")),
            Buyer = list(inputId = "Buyer", label = h5("Buyer:")),
            Site = list(inputId = "Site", label = h5("Site:")),
            #Buyer = list(inputId = "Buyer", title = "Buyer:"),
            Part_Number = list(inputId = "Part_Number", label = h5("Part Number:"))
          ), inline = FALSE
          
        ))),
        status = "primary"),
        fluidRow(
          selectInput("select1","Part Tracker", choices = unique(mydataTS$Part_Number))
        ),
        fluidRow(
        tags$image(src = "B.png",height= "30%" , width= "30%" ,align = "left"),
        tags$image(src = "A.png",height= "30%" , width= "30%" ,align = "right")
        ),
        width = 4 ),
          )
```

Also here is the server side

```
mydataTS1 <-excel_sheets("~/Desktop/Updated-Dashboard-code3:15/Prototype v5/Dashboard-TSData4.xlsx") %>% map_df(~read_xlsx("~/Desktop/Updated-Dashboard-code3:15/Prototype v5/Dashboard-TSData4.xlsx",.))

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    
  vars_r <- reactive({input$vars})

  res_mod <- callModule(module = selectizeGroupServer,id = "my-filters", data = mydataTS1, vars = vars_r, inline = FALSE)
  print(res_mod) 
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(res_mod())
    res_mod()
  })
```

[OUTPUT OF UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8kK.png)

My apologies for the bad first question, I'm new to SO but learning.
Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, you've not given us the code from your UI.  You've given us *part of* your code from your UI.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Wrapping your code in a call to `fluidPage`, I am unable to reproduce the issue.  This suggests your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using the `inline` parameter? It needs to be set in the server and the UI part. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716955/selectizegroupui-unable-to-set-filter-widths-inline-true-error-when-aws-dep/70726085#70726085) related post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ive edited my initial question to include much more of the code, let me know if anything else is necessary